# error al consumir web services en IIS 10

Tags: webservice, iis

sigo teniendo problemas al consumir un web service, cuando lo ejecuto en local, funciona correctamente, pero cuando lo subo a un servidor con IIS 10. al momento de consumirlo, me sale este error. alguien lo ha pasado el mismo error, como puedo solucionarlo?, gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes 2 aplicaciones una con el webservice y otra que lo consume??